# Pandas: drop out of sequence row

Tags: pandas

My Pandas df:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """date   value          
"2015-09-01"    71.925000
"2015-09-06"    71.625000
"2015-09-11"    71.333333
"2015-09-12"    64.571429
"2015-09-21"    72.285714

"""

df = pd.read_table(io.StringIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)

df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)
```

I Given a user input date ( 01-09-2015).
I would like to keep only those date where difference between date and input date is multiple of 5.

Expected output:

```
input = 01-09-2015

df:
        date      value
0 2015-09-01  71.925000
1 2015-09-06  71.625000
2 2015-09-11  71.333333
3 2015-09-21  72.285714
```

My Approach so far:
I am taking the delta between input_date and date in pandas and saving this delta in separate column.
If delta%5 == 0, keep the row else drop. Is this the best that can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) for filter by mask, here convert input values to datetimes and then timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
input1 = '01-09-2015'

df = df[df.date.sub(pd.to_datetime(input1)).dt.days % 5 == 0]
print (df)
        date      value
0 2015-09-01  71.925000
1 2015-09-06  71.625000
2 2015-09-11  71.333333
4 2015-09-21  72.285714
```